# icefaces configuration

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee, icefaces-3

I am trying to work with icefaces3. I made some examples and they perfectly work, 
but when I try some examples from

http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=compatMenu&exp=menuBar

I get errors in:

```
import org.icefaces.samples.showcase.metadata.annotation.ComponentExample;
import org.icefaces.samples.showcase.metadata.annotation.ExampleResource;
import org.icefaces.samples.showcase.metadata.annotation.ExampleResources;
import org.icefaces.samples.showcase.metadata.annotation.Menu;
import org.icefaces.samples.showcase.metadata.annotation.MenuLink;
import org.icefaces.samples.showcase.metadata.annotation.ResourceType;
import org.icefaces.samples.showcase.metadata.context.ComponentExampleImpl;
```

Eclipse can find these classes instead the  necessary jars are automatically added to my project.

There are  icefaces jars shown in  package Explorer (which are automatically added by eclipse).

icefaces.jar

commons-logging.jar

icefaces-compat.jar

jxl.jar

krysalis-jCharts-1.0.0-alpha-1.jar

icefaces-ace.jar

icepush.jar

Please how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you post the errors you are getting?

Comment: the problem that eclipse don't find these package. when i put the cursor over the mark i get this notification  The import org.icefaces.samples.showcase.metadata.annotation.ComponentExample cannot be resolved

when i try to focus on  the ICEfaces-3.0.1-src i found these class at 
ICEfaces-3.0.1-src\icefaces\samples\showcase\showcase\src\main\java\org\icefaces\samples\showcase\metadata\annotationi 

try to add all the project  ICEfaces-3.0.1-src in my project then i try to add ICEfaces-3.0.1-bin and i try to add all the jars i found in ICEfaces-3.0.1-bin project

 but none of my ideas succeed

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any of these classes. Remove all showcases annotations like @ComponentExample, @ExampleResources and @Menu. These annotations are just needed for icefaces showcase portal. Not very well done by icefaces...

Comment: Off topic but IceFaces is a fork of PrimeFaces, in case you don't know. http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1750